# Make SKView paused on creation?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Im adding a `SKView` to my `UIViewController` and then adding a `SKScene` to it.

I want to `pause` the `SKView` when created and added and later unpause it.

```
// In viewController viewDidLoad()
let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.bounds)
skView.paused = true

println(skView.paused)     // Prints true
gcd.async(.Main) { println(skView.paused) } // Prints false 

let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)

self.view.addSubview(skView)
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

I first set the paused to true but it somehow changes (not by me) to false again :S

I tried setting it in `GameScene` `didMoveToView()` but it still prints out false in the async closure and all children are doing their stuff and update function is getting called :SSS

If I set it to false in the async closure it works but the update function is called once, I dont want that and I dont want to rely on async which can be unreliable.

What Im I doing wrong?

Comment: calls to update method are not affected by the paused property. only actions and physics simulation

Comment: Yes it does, I tested it and it works if I set paused to true after a little while. The problem here is that the paused property is changing back to true and I dont know why.